# how to share CFUUIDCreate to the web

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services

I got UUID using CFUUIDCreate. Now I need to share it to the web. In case with UDID I did it using .mobileconfig. But how can I get UUID from the web page?

Comment: what do you mean by share it to the web? send it to a server endpoint?

Comment: I mean user goes to the website, and website gets this UUID via browser